# Problem installing Canvas LMS using docker

Tags: docker, open-source, canvas-lms

I am trying to install a development version of Canvas LMS using this [Quick Start Guide](https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/wiki/Quick-Start).
Input:

```
./script/docker_dev_setup.sh
```

The first time I ran it, I had the following output:

```
|\\   ___|\\   \_\_  |\\   \______\_  |\\  \\    /  /|\\   \_\_  |\\   \
\\ \\  \_|\\ \\  |\\  \\ \\  \\ \\  \\ \\  \\  /  / | \\  |\\  \\ \\  \___|\_
\\ \\  \\    \\ \\   \_\_  \\ \\  \\ \\  \\ \\  /  / / \\ \\   \_\_  \\ \_  \
\\ \\  \_\\ \\  \\ \\  \\ \\  \\ \\  \\ \\    / /   \\ \\  \\ \\  |__|\\  \
\\ \____\\ \__\\ \_\\ \__\\ \__\\ \__/ /     \\ \__\\ \__\____\_\\  \
|__\_\____||||__||| ||||/       ||||\_\
|_\_\_|

Welcome! This script will guide you through the process of setting up a
Canvas development environment.
Log file is /home/mike/canvas-lms/log/docker_dev_setup.log

> It looks like you're using Linux. Let's set that up.

> Checking Dependencies...
> script/common/utils/common.sh: line 159: ((: 0
> 0
> 0
> 0 : syntax error in expression (error token is "0
> 0
> 0 ")
> Canvas recommends using dory for a reverse proxy allowing you to
> access canvas at http://canvas.docker. Detailed instructions
> are available at https://github.com/FreedomBen/dory.
> If you want to install it, run 'gem install dory' then rerun this script.
> Would you like to skip dory? \[y/n\] n
> Install dory then rerun this script.
```

So, I stalled dory and ran the script again.
Input:

```
./script/docker_dev_setup.sh
```

Output after installing dory:

```
______________________________________________

|\\   ___|\\   \_\_  |\\   \______\_  |\\  \\    /  /|\\   \_\_  |\\   \
\\ \\  \_|\\ \\  |\\  \\ \\  \\ \\  \\ \\  \\  /  / | \\  |\\  \\ \\  \___|\_
\\ \\  \\    \\ \\   \_\_  \\ \\  \\ \\  \\ \\  /  / / \\ \\   \_\_  \\ \_  \
\\ \\  \_\\ \\  \\ \\  \\ \\  \\ \\  \\ \\    / /   \\ \\  \\ \\  |__|\\  \
\\ \____\\ \__\\ \_\\ \__\\ \__\\ \__/ /     \\ \__\\ \__\____\_\\  \
|__\_\____||||__||| ||||/       ||||\_\
|_\_\_|

Welcome! This script will guide you through the process of setting up a
Canvas development environment.
Log file is /home/mike/canvas-lms/log/docker_dev_setup.log

> It looks like you're using Linux. Let's set that up.

> Checking Dependencies...
> script/common/utils/common.sh: line 159: ((: 0
> 0
> 0
> 0 : syntax error in expression (error token is "0
> 0
> 0 ")

> Starting dory...
> /usr/local/bin/dory:25:in `load': cannot load such file -- /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/dory-1.2.0/bin/dory (LoadError)         from /usr/local/bin/dory:25:in `\<main\>'
> /usr/local/bin/dory:25:in `load': cannot load such file -- /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/dory-1.2.0/bin/dory (LoadError)         from /usr/local/bin/dory:25:in `\<main\>'

> Something went wrong with dory! Exiting script.

/o\\ Something went wrong. Check /home/mike/canvas-lms/log/docker_dev_setup.log for details.
```

I tried to track down the second error:

```
/usr/local/bin/dory:25:in `load': cannot load such file -- /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/dory-1.2.0/bin/dory (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/bin/dory:25:in `<main>'
/usr/local/bin/dory:25:in `load': cannot load such file -- /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/dory-1.2.0/bin/dory (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/bin/dory:25:in `<main>'
```

I open this file and see:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby3.0
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'dory' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

Gem.use_gemdeps

version = ">= 0.a"

str = ARGV.first
if str
  str = str.b[/\A_(.*)_\z/, 1]
  if str and Gem::Version.correct?(str)
    version = str
    ARGV.shift
  end
end

if Gem.respond_to?(:activate_bin_path)
load Gem.activate_bin_path('dory', 'dory', version)
else
gem "dory", version
load Gem.bin_path("dory", "dory", version)
end
```

The error appears to be here:

```
if Gem.respond_to?(:activate_bin_path)
load Gem.activate_bin_path('dory', 'dory', version)
else
```

Can I somehow change the path to allow the process to continue, or is there something that I can do to the folder structure that will allow it to continue?

Answer (score 0):

if installed dory
check

```
dory status
```

if running  , run sh file else run this command first

```
dory up
```